# Objectify task queue in a transaction example

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

What I am trying to do is make a datastore put, and if it is successful, make a Search API put as well. This [link](https://sookocheff.com/post/appengine/syncing-search-documents-with-datastore-entities/) has some useful info on how to do this with python, but I need an Objectify (Java) example.

I read that the way to do this is to have a transaction and then a task queue inside of that if it succeeds? Not sure how to do that so looking for a solid example.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload for `Queue.add()` that accepts a transaction object. So, during your transaction, enqueue a deferred task that will sync to search, passing it `ofy().getTransaction()`.

The task can be quite simple - the only state is a key object. You load the entity, make the search document, write it to the index.

Comment: Do you happen to have a code snippet of what you described in the first paragraph? I have been looking at the objectify docs but I am a bit confused of how to connect the pieces.

Comment: Take a look at this class and the files in that package. It's what I use to wrap queues and provide a better interface:  https://github.com/stickfigure/gstrap/blob/master/gstrap/src/main/java/com/voodoodyne/gstrap/taskqueue/QueueHelper.java

Comment: Couldn't you just have a transaction that writes to the datastore and returns true or false. Then, if true, just run the next bit of code to write a Search API entry? The code to sync to search api isn't that long. Or is there some other benefit to using a deferred task?

Comment: The goal is to ensure that the search data never falls out of sync with the datastore data. If there is no transactional link, then an error in the app, network timeout, or even crash of the hardware will result in inconsistencies. With a transactional task, the change is guaranteed to propagate eventually.